# Pandas - returning adjacent columns in pandas based on index result

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and would like some help. 
I have 2 lists A & B, A is the data that I am organising, and B is my list of data that I am using as a reference.

Below is an example of list A.

```
     A
   Oringinal_String    Shortened_String    Price
1    BR3 6yh             BR3               56789
2    BL2 8hs             BL2               93882
3    AR3 9hs             AR3               67890
4    UB3 7hy             UB3               23453
5    BR3 7yh             BR3               76801
```

Below is an example of list B

```
     B
     Oringinal_String    Shortened_String   Area
1    BR3 6yb             BR3                 MAN
2    BL2 2xs             BL2                 LON
3    XA2 1wl             XA2                 NEW
4    UB3 9xv             UB3                 LUT
```

I would like to find when A['shortened_string'] is found in B['shortened_string'] and append B['Area'] to A.

I think i have managed to index to find when A occurs in B but cant seem to get out B['Area'] when my index is true, not sure if this was the right way of doing it ?

```
A.loc[A.index.isin(B['shortened_strin'])]
```

I am hoping to get out:

```
  A
     Oringinal_String    Shortened_String  Price    Area
1    BR3 6yh             BR3               56789    MAN
2    BL2 8hs             BL2               93882    LON
3    AR3 9hs             AR3               67890    
4    UB3 7hy             UB3               23453    LUT
5    BR3 7yh             BR3               76801    MAN
```

-Key notes there are duplicates of A['shortened_strin']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to let

```
A['Area'] = A.merge(B, on='shortened_strin', how='left')['Area']
```

Answer (score 1):

Merge and some cleanup

```
A.merge(B, on = 'Shortened_String', how = 'left', suffixes = ('', '_y')).drop('Oringinal_String_y',1).fillna('')


    Oringinal_String    Shortened_String    Price   Area
0   BR3 6yh             BR3                 56789   MAN
1   BL2 8hs             BL2                 93882   LON
2   AR3 9hs             AR3                 67890   
3   UB3 7hy             UB3                 23453   LUT
4   BR3 7yh             BR3                 76801   MAN
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map`

```
dfa['area'] = dfa.iloc[:,1].map(dfb.set_index("'Shortened_String'").iloc[:,1])
```

change `.iloc[:,1]` for `.loc[:, 'Shortened_String']` if the columns `'Shortened_String'` is not in position `1` in your df.

Output:

```
    'Oringinal_String'  'Shortened_String'  'Price' area
1   BR3 6yh             BR3                  56789  MAN
2   BL2 8hs             BL2                  93882  LON
3   AR3 9hs             AR3                  67890  NaN
4   UB3 7hy             UB3                  23453  LUT
5   BR3 7yh             BR3                  76801  MAN
```